# Scalatest from Maven: How to tag and filter out an entire Suite?

Tags: xml, scala, maven, scalatest, scala-maven-plugin

I have a Maven project and I'm using the [scalatest-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bravegag/scalatest-maven-plugin) to configure scalatest. I'm using scalatest 3.0.0 however I can't manage to tag and filter out an entire Suite.

As reference, I have used the blog [Tag a whole ScalaTest suite (update for Java 8)](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/2015/08/26/tag-scalatest-suite) but this doesn't seem to work from Maven.

I created a new `Skip` tag defined as follows:

```
package tags;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@org.scalatest.TagAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Skip {}
```

Then I tag my test Suite like this:

```
@tags.Skip
class AcceptanceTest extends FeatureSpec { ...
```

I then configure my scalatest-maven-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <tagsToExclude>tags.Skip</tagsToExclude>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then running `mvn clean install -X` I see (which correctly passes the -l Tag exclusion CLI argument to Scalatest):

```
[DEBUG] Forking ScalaTest via: cmd.exe /X /C "java -Dbasedir=mydir 
        org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R -l tags.Skip ...
```

but the `AcceptanceTest` Suite gets nevertheless executed. I have also tried tagging the Suite like this without success:

```
class AcceptanceTest extends Tag("tags.Skip") with FeatureSpecLike { ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To separate execution of integration tests I used maven profiles:

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                        <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                        <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                        <tagsToExclude>org.example.testkit.annotations.IntegrationTestSuite</tagsToExclude>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                        <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                        <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                        <tagsToInclude>org.example.testkit.annotations.IntegrationTestSuite</tagsToInclude>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then I marked integration tests accordingly

```
@IntegrationTestSuite
class ExampleTest extends PropSpec with MockitoSugar with BeforeAndAfterAll with EndpointTestHelper {
```

to run unit tests I run

```
mvn test
```

for integration tests

```
mvn test -Pintegration-test
```

UPD:

```
package org.example.testkit.annotations;

import org.scalatest.TagAnnotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@TagAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface IntegrationTestSuite {}
```

We use scala 2.11, scalatest 2.2.6, maven 2, java 8.

Comment: Interesting ... can you update your answer and add your definition of `IntegrationTestSuite` and then your scalatest, maven and java versions?

Comment: Thank you! I am constrained to using Scala 2.10.x maybe that's the issue ... I have to test it with Scala 2.11.x

Answer (score 1):

You can pass tags that you need dynamically without creating new profiles:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tagsToInclude>${tagsToInclude}</tagsToInclude>
                <tagsToExclude>${tagsToExclude}</tagsToExclude>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Some tag definition example:

```
package com.foo.tags;

import org.scalatest.TagAnnotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@TagAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Skip {}
```

And finally you can pass your tags from CLI dynamically in the following way:

```
mvn -DtagsToExclude=com.foo.tags.Skip test
```